# Python group by array column and partition by row number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array as below

```
[('test1@test.com', '220104'), ('test2@test.com', '220104'), ('test3@test.com', '220106'), ('test4@test.com', '220106')]
```

Here the email ID will be always unique. But the date may come same. The date format will be always YYMMDD. So, the number will change once the date changes

I need output in short as below. The third column basically represents the number of emails of that day

```
'test1@test.com', '220104', 1
'test2@test.com', '220104', 2
'test3@test.com', '220106', 1
'test4@test.com', '220106', 2
```

so if the 5th email come, on the same date as the 6th then the output will be

```
'test1@test.com', '220104', 1
'test2@test.com', '220104', 2
'test3@test.com', '220106', 1
'test4@test.com', '220106', 2
'test4@test.com', '220106', 3
```

Comment: What's the 3rd column in your output represent?

Comment: updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) here:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('test1@test.com', '220104'), ('test2@test.com', '220104'), ('test3@test.com', '220106'), ('test4@test.com', '220106')], columns=['email','date'])
df['date_grouped_index'] = df.groupby('date').cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: cumcount is the key. Thank you for the help. I am accepting the answer.